# Pandas Way of Weighted Average in a Large DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I do have a large dataset (around 8 million rows x 25 columns) in Pandas and I am struggling to find a way to compute weighted average on this dataframe which in turn creates another data frame.

Here is how my dataset looks like (very simplified version of it):

```
                   prec     temp
location_id hours             
135         1      12.0      4.0
            2      14.0      4.1
            3      14.3      3.5
            4      15.0      4.5
            5      15.0      4.2
            6      15.0      4.7
            7      15.5      5.1
136         1      12.0      4.0
            2      14.0      4.1
            3      14.3      3.5
            4      15.0      4.5
            5      15.0      4.2
            6      15.0      4.7
            7      15.5      5.1
```

- I have a multi-index on [location_id, hours]. I have around 60k locations and 140 hours for each location (making up the 8 million rows).
- The rest of the data is numeric (float) or categorical. I have only included 2 columns here, normally there are around 20 columns.
- What I am willing to do is to create a new data frame that is basically a weighted average of this data frame. The requirements indicate that 12 of these `location_id`s should be averaged out by a specified weight to form the `combined_location_id` values.
- For example, `location_id`s 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23 with their appropriate weights (separate data coming in from another data frame) should be weighted averaged to from the `combined_location_id` `CL_1`'s data.
- That is a lot of data to handle and I wasn't able to find a completely Pandas way of solving it. Therefore, I went with a `for loop` approach. It is extremely slow and I am sure this is not the right way to do it:

```
def __weighted(self, ds, weights):
  return np.average(ds, weights=weights)

f = {'hours': 'first', 'location_id': 'first', 
'temp': lambda x: self.__weighted(x, weights), 'prec': lambda x: self.__weighted(x, weights)}

data_frames = []
for combined_location in all_combined_locations:
   mapped_location_ids = combined_location.location_ids
   weights = combined_location.weights_of_location_ids
   data_for_this_combined_location = pd.concat(df_data.loc[df_data.index.get_level_values(0) == location_id] for location_id in mapped_location_ids)
   data_grouped_by_distance = data_for_this_combined_location.groupby("hours", as_index=False)
   data_grouped_by_distance = data_grouped_by_distance.agg(f)
   data_frames.append(data_grouped_by_distance)

df_combined_location_data = pd.concat(data_frames)
df_combined_location_data.set_index(['location_id', 'hours'], inplace=True)
```

- This works well functionally, however the performance and the memory consumption is horrible. It is taking over 2 hours on my dataset and that is currently not acceptable. The existence of the for loop is an indicator that this could be handled better.
- Is there a better/faster way to implement this?

Comment: 8 m row  ？？ how you load it to panda....

Comment: @YOBEN_S Coming in from a batch of 30 CSV files.

Comment: Will all_combined_locations have overlap in location_id ?

Comment: @YOBEN_S You mean will all the mappings of  `all_combined_locations` have corresponding locatoin_ids?  Yes.

Comment: I mean different combined_location  in all_combined_locations have overlap ?

Comment: @YOBEN_S Yes! There is overlap.

Comment: r u open for using Dask?

Comment: @spiralarchitect That is exactly where I ended up :) I have spent some time researching  how to handle such data sets in the presence of memory limitations and Dask seems to be a good approach. Thanks for the suggestion. If you can maybe write up some details on it, that would be great. I would accept your answer and close this one.

Comment: @Guven: I am trying to simulate the data. Will let you know. :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw you can reduce one for loop with `mapped_location_ids`

```
data_for_this_combined_location = df_data.loc[df_data.index.get_level_values(0).isin(mapped_location_ids)]
```